# Directly Hitting static css file url( http://localhost:3000/css/style.css ) response is working but not applied on ejs template elements?

Tags: css, node.js, express, path, ejs

Hye guys I am newbie in node.js . 
I am working with ejs partial template . I have been stuck for days in this issue where i have **public/css/style.css** file in root directory .
where i am accessing this file from ***views/contact.ejs*** and ***views/home.ejs***

**Contact.ejs**
!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/style.css" type=“text/css“>
</head>

<body>
    <%- include('partialComponents/naviagations.ejs') %>
        <H3>CONTACTS US !</H3>
        <h2>LEARN THE BEST CODE TECHNIQUES HERE ....</h2>
        <h2>EJS FILE TEMPLATE </h2>
</body>

</html>
```

**main.js**

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
//app.set('views', '/views'); // settings the path to view folder to express can locate
//by default express will check the view folder in first root to the js file

app.use(express.static('public'))
app.get('/profile/:id', (req, res) => {

    var data = {
        age: 23,
        job: 'software developer',
        hobbies: ['eating', 'fishing', 'gaming']
    }
    console.log('hey');
    res.render('profile', { name: req.params.id, data: data });
});

app.get('/home', (req, res) => {

    res.render('home');
});
app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    res.render('home');
});
app.get('/contact', (req, res) => {

    res.render('contact');
});



app.listen(3000);
// console.log(__dirname + "");
```

**style.css**

```css
body {
    background-color: skyblue;
    text-align: center;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
    color: white;
}

h2 {
    color: white;
}

.testid {
    color: red;
}
```

here is my file structure [image: File structure]

Comment: i think its `../public/css/style.css`

Comment: @MatanSanbira already tried this but not working

Comment: @Pete removing public means public is built in recognizable directory for node ?? secondly i have added classes dom elements for headings rather than using  headings tags  as you suggested but still not working .

Comment: @Pete according to my understanding this `app.use(express.static('public'))` line is responsible for this response `http://localhost:3000/css/style.css` that we don't need to mention **public** because express automatically sets the directory for static files , but in case of style sheet only mentioning `/css/style.css` i don't know how `.ejs` file refer to this style sheet

Comment: @Pete I do apologize if you feel like i was fighting in fact was trying to correcting my concepts, just came to you after trying because your suggested solution was not working .

Comment: @Pete just played around your suggestions worked like a charm thanks a lot ! please post answer so i could accept it .Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ‍ You're missing in the `<link href="">` because you have set `public` as your static folder, your style is in the location:`http://localhost:3000/css/style.css`. That is why when you call `/public/css/style.css` it cannot be found, because it will look for the`public` folder inside the `public` folder and you do not have it other than the`css` folder there..

**So**, You can change your `<link href=""/>` with this code below :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" href="text/css">
```

**For an example:** You can see on my codesandbox

- Sandbox code: https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-borg-ghwc0
- For view only: https://ghwc0.sse.codesandbox.io/contact

I hope it can help you .